# Run Java without Array Bounds checking, Cast checking, etc

Tags: java, optimization, profiling

I have a Java program that does many small array operations.  I've run it and verified that it produces no errors, but it is slower than expected.  I'm assuming a lot of this slowdown is related to checking array bounds, etc.

Is there a way to disable all error checking so I can run my program faster (at risk that it just crashes, rather then generates an intelligible error)?

Comment: It you can instead explain the problam your arrays are trying to solve it would be easier to help you out. It more or less never recommended to try to make your code faster by hacks. The java compiler will beat your code almost 100% of the time.

Comment: How did you come by the conclusion that the problem was bounds checking? Did you profile your application? Did you identify bounds checking as the bottleneck?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not possible. The Java Language Specification describes the circumstances under which casts and array accesses throw exceptions, but makes no mention of a mechanism to disable this behaviour.

Throwing of `ClassCastException` is described in [JLS Section 15.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.6):

> - A cast expression (§15.16) throws a ClassCastException if a cast is found to be impermissible at run time.

Array bounds checking is described in [JLS Section 15.10.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.4):

> At run time, evaluation of an array access expression behaves as follows:
>
> - First, the array reference expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the array access completes abruptly for the same reason and the index expression is not evaluated.
> - Otherwise, the index expression is evaluated. If this evaluation completes abruptly, then the array access completes abruptly for the same reason.
> - Otherwise, if the value of the array reference expression is null, then a NullPointerException is thrown.
> - **Otherwise, the value of the array reference expression indeed refers to an array. If the value of the index expression is less than zero, or greater than or equal to the array's length, then an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` is thrown.**
> - Otherwise, the result of the array access is the variable of type T, within the array, selected by the value of the index expression.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not possible as this would break the JVM in case of error.